# What if you avoid popping your joints entirely?

Tags: bones, joints, cartilage

This question is the opposite of [Are there any side effects to cracking knuckles?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/are-there-any-side-effects-to-cracking-knuckles) . When you wake in the morning and stretch joints pop or crack. So what would happen health wise if you where to avoid movements to avoid popping your joints in the long run?